# Using gevent-socketio paster integration causes my application to be unresponsive

Tags: pyramid, gevent-socketio, redis-py

I am writing a Pyramid application that relies on [gevent-socketio](http://gevent-socketio.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) and [redis](https://redis-py.readthedocs.org/en/latest/). However, I noticed that **when I navigate  away from the view that establishes the socket.io connection, my application becomes unresponsive**. In order to try and isolate the issue, I created another bare-bones application and discovered that using *pubsub.listen()* was causing the issue:

```
class TestNamespace(BaseNamespace):

    def initialize(self):
        self.spawn(self.emitter)

    def emitter(self):
        client = redis.pubsub()
        client.subscribe('anything')
        for broadcast in client.listen():
            if broadcast['type'] != 'message':
                continue
```

The way I'm starting up my application is as follows:

```
pserve --reload development.ini
```

However, I can only get my application to work if use use the *serve.py* from the [examples](https://github.com/abourget/gevent-socketio/tree/master/examples/pyramid_backbone_redis_chat):

```
import os.path

from socketio.server import SocketIOServer
from pyramid.paster import get_app
from gevent import monkey; monkey.patch_all()

HERE = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))

if __name__ == '__main__':

    app = get_app(os.path.join(HERE, 'development.ini'))
    print 'Listening on port http://0.0.0.0:8080 and on port 10843 (flash policy server)'

    SocketIOServer(('0.0.0.0', 8080), app,
        resource="socket.io", policy_server=True,
        policy_listener=('0.0.0.0', 10843)).serve_forever()
```

Unfortunatey this is rather cumbersome for development as I lose *--reload* functionality. Ideally I'd like to use the [paster integration entry point](https://gevent-socketio.readthedocs.org/en/latest/server_integration.html#directly-through-gevent)

Another thing I noticed is that the [gevent-sockectio paster integration](https://github.com/abourget/gevent-socketio/blob/master/socketio/server.py) does not monkey patch gevent, whereas the examples server.py does.

**How can I get pserve --reload to work with gevent-socketio?**

I've uploaded my test application to github: https://github.com/m-martinez/iotest

Answer (score 0):

Under [server:main] in your ini file.

```
use = egg:gevent-socketio#paster
transports = websocket, xhr-multipart, xhr-polling
policy_server = True
host = 0.0.0.0
port = 6543
```

If you get an error make sure you using the latest version of gevent-socketio.

Comment: I'm using the current version on github instead of the one on pypi. I tried what you suggested (except I'm using `port = 8080`) and it's still giving me problems. Thanks for looking at it though!

Comment: That's very odd. Take a look at http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zhh_N5pmHBY . He goes through the setup step by step.

Answer (score 0):

With no success using **egg:gevent-socketio#paster**, I ended up using **gunicorn** with **watchdog** to achieve what I wanted for development:

```
  watchmedo auto-restart \
            --pattern "*.py;*.ini" \
            --directory ./iotest/ \
            --recursive \
            -- \
            gunicorn --paste ./iotest/development.ini
```

This is what my [server:main] section looks like:

```
[server:main]
use = egg:gunicorn#main
worker_class = socketio.sgunicorn.GeventSocketIOWorker
host = 0.0.0.0
port = 8080
debug = True
logconfig = %(here)s/development.ini
```